# Java Single Inheritance and Exception/Throwable classes

Tags: java, inheritance

I understand that the language specification declares only single inheritance, but I'm puzzled over how this one example *seems* to break the rule.

If I write an `Exception` class, I'll write:

```
public class MyException extends Exception {
    //class body
}
```

Only, if you [look here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html), you'll notice that the class `Exception` extends `Throwable`.

So to my mind, we have (the theoretical code example)

```
 public class MyException extends Throwable, Exception {
    //class body
 }
```

Why is this *not* so?

I suppose this is done the same way that every class extends `Object` but can also be subclassed once?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There can be multiple levels in the hierarchy. A class may extend a class that itself extends another class (or implements an interface). This is not the same (in theory or in practice) as one class extending two classes itself.

Interfaces in Java do provide much of the same functionality as multiple inheritance in other languages (because a class *can* implement multiple interfaces), but that's not what you're seeing here. This is standard single inheritance with multiple ancestor classes.

It might help to picture a (biologically weird) family tree in which every child has exactly one parent. Those children may also have a grandparent, but never more than one node at any level of the structure.

You're imagining a structure that looks like this:

```
A   B
 \ /
  C
```

But it's actually like this:

```
A
|
B
|
C
```

The most obvious difference is that changes to `A` do not affect instances of `B` in the first graph, but would impact `B` in the second.

Comment: Exactly. One parent, infinite grandparents.

Comment: A Volkswagen is a car, and a car is a vehicle, and a vehicle is an Object. This is single inheritance.

Comment: @cosiKa - Added a little more that extends your grandparent metaphor.

Answer (score 0):

> I suppose this is done the same way that every class extends Object
>   but can also be subclassed once?

Not quite. Think of it this way:

```
class A { }
```

can be thought of as

```
class A extends Object { }
```

but

```
class A extends B { }
```

should be though of as

```
class B extends Object { }
class A extends B { }
```

and not

```
class A extends B, Object { }
```

In the class inheritance hierarchy (not counting implementations of interfaces) each class can have a single parent, except for `Object` which the root of the tree.

Answer (score 0):

It is a chain of inheritance

Object -> Throwable -> Exception -> MyException

See here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html

Answer (score 0):

So in your example `MyException` is also a `Throwable` in addition to being an `Exception` .  Therefore the hierarchy is like so:

```
Throwable -> Exception -> MyException
```

So lets say that the hierarchy actually looked like this:

```
Throwable -> MyException  
Exception -> MyException
```

While still true that `MyException` is both a `Throwable` and an `Exception`.  For an explanation as to what multiple inheritance brings look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem):

"In object-oriented programming languages with multiple inheritance, the diamond problem (sometimes referred to as the "deadly diamond of death"[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond_problem)) is an ambiguity that arises when two classes B and C inherit from A, and class D inherits from both B and C. If D calls a method defined in A (and does not override the method), and B and C have overridden that method differently, then from which class does it inherit: B, or C?"

Answer (score 0):

A class can extend one class that can extend another class. But one class can't inherit two classes. It will cause **ambiguity**. That's why java **don't support multiple inheritance**.

MyException extending Exception which is extending Throwable. That is the chain of inheritance. It won't cause ambiguity.

Comment: It's **not really** necessary **to make** every few words **bold**.